# How to attach an IP address located in a shared subnetwork on an instance?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I am trying to create an instance with an internal static IP address located in a subnetwork shared with my project on GCP with Terraform.

But when the creation of the instance goes on, i have the following error :

> Error 400: Invalid value for field 'resource.networkInterfaces[0].accessConfigs[0].natIP': '10.25.64.83'.The specified external IP address '10.25.64.83' was not found in region 'europe-west3'

Here is the concerned part of the terraform script :

```
## Retrieve shared subnet 
data "google_compute_subnetwork" "shared-snet" {
  name    = "shared-snet"
  project = "shared-project"
  region  = "europe-west3"
}

## Create internal static IP address in the shared subnet
resource "google_compute_address" "shared-subnet-ip" {
  name         = "shared-subnet-ip"
  address_type = "INTERNAL"
  subnetwork   = data.google_compute_subnetwork.shared-snet.self_link
}

## Create instance with the IP previously created
resource "google_compute_instance" "my-instance" {
  name         = "my-instance"
  machine_type = "n1-standard-1"
  zone         = "europe-west3-a"
  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      image = "windows-server-2019-dc-core-v20230712"  # Image Windows Server 2019
      size  = 80
    }
  }
  network_interface {
        subnetwork   = data.google_compute_subnetwork.shared-snet.self_link
    access_config {
          nat_ip = "${google_compute_address.shared-subnet-ip.address}"
    }
  }
}
```

The shared subnet (and so the IP address) is located in the same region as my current project, i also specified it at the beginning of my terraform script :

```
provider "google" {
  project = "my-project"
  region  = "europe-west3"
}
```

What's wrong ? It's like the IP address was in a different region but it shouldn't.

Comment: Is the IP address in the same project? You cannot use an IP address in a different project. The key is project/region must be the same for regional IP addresses. The lookup is occurring in your project and was not found.

Answer (score 0):

using `access-config` means that you want an external address. If you re-read the error message, you'll see the problem.

try some variation of this instead:

```
  network_interface {
    network    = var.network
    subnetwork = data.google_compute_subnetwork.shared-snet.self_link
    network_ip = "${google_compute_address.shared-subnet-ip.address}"
  }
```